# Randomly rearranging data points when creating cross-validation indices?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, cross-validation

I have a dataset where the columns corresponds to features (predictors) and the rows correspond to data points. The data points are extracted in a structured way, i.e. they are sorted. I will use either [crossvalind](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/crossvalind.html) or [cvpartition](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/stats/cvpartition.html) from Matlab for stratified cross-validation.

If I use the above function, do I still have to first randomly rearrange the data points (rows)?

Comment: No, `crossvalind` or `cvpartition` will randomly shuffle your data for you.  If you read the very beginning of the docs for each page, the word *random* appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These functions shuffle your data internally, as you can see in the docs

> *Indices = crossvalind('Kfold', N, K)* returns **randomly generated** indices for a K-fold cross-validation of N observations. Indices contains equal (or approximately equal) proportions of the integers 1 through K that define a partition of the N observations into K disjoint subsets. **Repeated calls return different randomly generated partitions**. K defaults to 5 when omitted. In K-fold cross-validation, K-1 folds are used for training and the last fold is used for evaluation. This process is repeated K times, leaving one different fold for evaluation each time.

However, if your data is structured in this sense, that object ith has some information about object i+1, then you should consider different kind of splitting. For example - if your data is actually a (locally) time series, typical random cv is **not a valid estimation technique**. Why? Because if your data actually contains clusters where knowledge of value of at least one element - gives you high probability of estimating remaining ones, what you will obtain in the end after applying CV is actually estimate of ability to do exactly so - predict **inside these clusters**. Thus if during actual real life usage of your model you expect to get completely new cluster - model you selected can be completely random there. In other words - if your data has some kind of internal cluster structure (or time series) your splits should cover this feature by splitting over clusters (thus instead of K random points splits you have K random clusters splits and so on).